# Unable to take LINQ query result into datatable, Cannot find table 0

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code,

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
result.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(Int32));
result.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
result.Columns.Add("a", typeof(string));
result.Columns.Add("b", typeof(string));
result.Columns.Add("c", typeof(OracleDate));
result.Columns.Add("d", typeof(OracleDecimal));
result.Columns.Add("e", typeof(string));
result.Columns.Add("f", typeof(string));
result.Columns.Add("g", typeof(string));


using (OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(ocommand))
{
      da.Fill(oDataSet);
}

using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
{
      adapter.Fill(dataSet);
}

IEnumerable<DataRow> query = from r in oDataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                             where !dataSet.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Any(r2 => (r["First Name"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == r2["xyz"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() &&
                                                r["e"].ToString().Trim().ToLower() == r2["abc"].ToString().Trim().ToLower()))
                             select r;

result = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Now what I am trying to acheive is that I have two dataset one from SQL and one from oracle. I am trying to get the data from Oracledataset which is not present in sql dataset according to the two column values.

the Linq query executes fine and I can see the table in query while debugging but when I try to execute,

```
result = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

It throws an error

> "Cannot find table 0."

Comment: Yes I did. But even if I try without creating columns, the result is same.

Comment: Have you checked both oDataSet & dataSet do have tables.

Comment: Yes they do, and in query when I see it as an object I can see the resultant table in it. during comparison it is not giving any error.

Comment: The column names are different in both datatables. that is why I am comparing two corresponding columns.

Comment: What is the full text of the exception thrown? Re. column names, as far as I can see CopyToDataTable will create a new table with column names from the result set, so anything previously set will be overwritten.

Comment: {System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.
   at System.Data.DataTableCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at CWS.CWS.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetFilteredLines>b__0(DataRow r) 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.DataTableExtensions.LoadTableFromEnumerable[T](IEnumerable`1 source, DataTable table, Nullable`1 options, FillErrorEventHandler errorHandler)
   at System.Data.DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at CWS.CWS.GetFilteredLines(GetFilteredLines_RQ request)

Comment: I think your `query`  returns `NULL` OR nothing.

Comment: Not too much help there :-(  The error is most usually found when a dataset has no tables (so dataset or oDataSet) - try putting a check for that before the linq query.. The exception occurs on CopyToDataTable due to deferred execution by Linq.

Comment: When `CopyToDataTable` used not directly to both dataset (dataset or oDataSet), it's better to check `query` first. You can put ` if (query.Count() >0)
            {` before you called `CopyToDataTable`

Comment: query.Count() also returns the same error. I am not sure why I can see the data while looking into query object. Could you please let me know a way to do it

Comment: I found a solution. There was a class library which manipulates the sql dataset and that was retutning null. Now I have fixed it so it started working.

Thank You All For Your Support